# Menu-item can't move center location

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I tried everything, but I couldn't bring this menu-item to the center. Here is my code:

```
    <div class="nav nav-tabs mb-2" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Network</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">End User</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-x1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-x1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-x1" aria-selected="false">Service Desk</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-x1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-x1-tab">dddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
     </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you can use `d-flex justify-content-center` bootstrap class.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="nav nav-tabs mb-2" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Network</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">End User</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-x1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-x1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-x1" aria-selected="false">Service Desk</a>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-x1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-x1-tab">dddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<center></center>` to center the navbar

```html
<center>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs mb-2" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Network</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">End User</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-x1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-x1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-x1" aria-selected="false">Service Desk</a>
    </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make title container as display:block and each title display:inline-block:

```css
.nav  {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav > a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nav nav-tabs mb-2" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Network</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">End User</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-x1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-x1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-x1" aria-selected="false">Service Desk</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-x1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-x1-tab">dddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
     </div>
```